# Adding new data with a file upload

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I have this form which has two fields, a name and a image field. Below is the code for the form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddNewRecipe", "Kitchen", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "addNewRecipe", data_partitionId = Model.Id }))
{
  <input type="text" placeholder="Recipe Name" name="newRecipeName" id="newRecipeName" value="" />
  <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="newRecipeImage" id="newRecipeImage" value="" />
  <button type="submit" class="button small" id="submitnewRecipe">Add</button>
}
```

When the form is submitted I am doing this in my JavaScript,

```
$('form#addNewRecipe').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = new FormData();
    var files = $('#newRecipeImage').get(0).files;
    if (files.length > 0) {
        data.append("UploadedImage", files[0]);
    }
    console.log(data); // no data is appended
});
```

What I am trying to do here is send the image file and name to the server so that they could be uploaded. Any insight on how to do that?

I am look for a nice solution in asp.net mvc c#.

Maybe my technique is not so good. I am open to criticism. :)

Comment: file cannot be upload with out full postback you need to use some plugin or hack using iframe to upload file without refreshing page

Comment: @mohsinali1317 did you try my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this in my project (working code)

jquery

```
var formData = new FormData();
var files = $('#newRecipeImage').get(0).files;
if (files.length > 0) {
    formData.append("img", files[0]);//files[0].name contains the file name
}
$.ajax({
   cache: false,
   type: 'POST',
   data: formData,
   processData: false,
   contentType: false,
   url: '/Sport/GetImagePreview',
   success: function(data) {
           //$("#yourImage").attr("src", "data:image/png;base64," + data.base64imgage);         
   },
   error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

   }
});
```

then in controller

```
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult GetImagePreview()
 {
     try
     {
     if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.AllKeys.Any())
     {
         var img = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["img"];//Request.FILES['img'].name contains the file name
         var ms = new MemoryStream();
         var logo = Image.FromStream(img.InputStream);
         logo = FixedSize(logo, 150, 150);
         logo.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

         return Json(new {base64imgage = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray())});
     }
     return Json("ko");
   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
      return Json("ko");
   }
 }
```